# Bison recursion behaving strangely with linked list

Tags: c, parsing, bison, yacc, bnf

I have a linked list-like struct:

```
typedef struct NODE
{
  NODE_TYPES type;
  struct NODE* curr;
  struct NODE* next;
} NODE;
```

and I have this recursive rule:

```
lines: stmt             {
                            root -> next = $1;
                            $1 -> next = NULL;
                            $$ = $1;

                        }
| lines stmt            {
                            $1 -> next = $2;
                            $2 -> next = NULL;
                            $$ = $2;

                        }
;
```

`stmt` is always a *pointer* to a `NODE` struct.

`root` is defined as `NODE *root` and then later, in the main function, allocated as such: `root = malloc(sizeof(NODE));`

However, printing my node list recursively starting from `root`, I only get the last node back. Why am I losing the data in between `root` and the last node?

Comment: Why `$$ = $2;`?

Comment: Because `$2` is the newest addition to `lines` when it is matched, so I set the whole group (`$$`) to it, acting as sort of the "current" pointer. What else would it be?

Comment: Oh now I see how that works.

Comment: @rici I'm not quite sure what you mean by this. Could you provide a quick solution maybe?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what's going wrong with your code because I can't see the crucial part. One possibility is that you're doing something like this in your `stmt` action: `{ NODE newNode = { /* contents */ }; $$ = &newNode; }`. But that seems like too obvious a problem, so it might well be something more subtle.

Comment: @rici Why would that be a problem?

Comment: Because the lifetime of an automatic variable ends when control flow exits from the block in which it was declared. That makes for a "dangling pointer", which is undefined behaviour (but the most likely is that the same memory is reused).

Comment: @rici So then should I do `NODE *new = malloc(sizeof(NODE))` in my rule's action block? And then assign `$$ = new`?

Comment: You can assign directly to `$$` as in my answer. But yes, you need to allocate on the heap. And then you need to free it when you are done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that you were setting the semantic value of `stmt` to point to a stack-allocated local variable. Since the local variable's lifetime expires as soon as the semantic action is done, that value is a dangling pointer and using it is Undefined Behaviour. (But in this case you will probably find that all the pointers refer to the same block of memory, whose contents will change every time that particular stack frame is reused.)

You need to ensure that the value of `stmt` is a pointer to a newly-allocated `NODE`:

```
stmt : /* ... something ... */ 
                  { $$ = malloc(sizeof *$$);
                    $$ = (NODE){/* ... */, .next = NULL; }
```

This is important. There's no good way of doing this without some kind of function which heap-allocates a new `NODE`. You can try to reduce malloc overhead by keeping a pool of `NODE`s and recycling them yourself, but since most modern `malloc` implementations do a good job of recycling small fixed-size allocations, it's premature optimization.

The linked list code will work for simple statements, but relying on a global variable to maintain the head of the list is not very scalable. It will make it impossible to parse compound statements (conditionals and loops, for example) because you'll end up reusing `root` for the internal statement lists. It's better to just build the list in the natural way (which will be backwards) and reverse it at the end:

```
stmts: stmt       /* Default action is fine */
     | stmts stmt { $$ = $2; $$->next = $1; }
line : stmts      { $$ = reverse($$); }
```

In this simple code, each time `stmts: stmts stmt` is reduced, it pushes the new NODE onto the *front* of the list, which obviously creates the list in reverse order. So when `line` is reduced (which will be after all the `stmt`s have been parsed), the list needs to be reversed. You can reverse in place:

```
NODE* reverse(NODE* last) {
  NODE* next = NULL;
  while (last) {
    NODE* tmp = last->next; 
    last->next = next;
    next = last;
    last = tmp;
  }
  return next;
}
```

That completely eliminates the need for the global `root`, so it is then possible for a compound statement to be correctly assembled.

Comment: Took me a sec to understand, but it works now. Thank you so much!